# I have a csv saved in a bucket on google cloud storage. Every line has data that I want to transfer to DataStore. How can I read the csv line by line?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I was going to used pandas, but I read that iterating over a dataframe is an inefficient solution.

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
doc = "example.csv"
blob=bucket.get_blob(doc) 
file=blob.download_as_string()
```

In the code above, file is a bytes object. I don't know how to take the bytes object and extract data from it line by line.

Comment: Might help https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/datastore/import

Answer (score 1):

Here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Maybe something like:

```
file=blob.download_as_string()

my_reader = csv.reader(file)
for row in my_reader:
    print(row)
```

If the CSV file has a header row, you can use a csv.DictReader to read it into a dictionary object instead. Depends on what you want to do with the data afterwards.